# What happens to the provisioning profile during the code signing process?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I am trying to find a way for a 3rd party developer to send me just the binary for an app (with the correct bundle id), so I can sign it with the correct certificate and send it to the app store.

I can tell xcode not to require a provisioning profile so it can be signed with any certificate. I can then use codesign to resign the binary with the correct certificate.
If my device then has the correct adhoc provisioning profile it will run the app ok.

My question really is, will this work for the app store? I am assuming the provisioning profile get baked into the binary somehow, but I'm not sure. What happens to the provisioning profile in an app store build?

Answer (score 1):

Could you not request the developer send you the source code so that you can compile & sign the binary yourself with the appropriate provisioning profile & certificate?

If that is a no go, could you not provide the developer a copy of your certificate and allow him to sign the app on your behalf? Check out [this link](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action), under the heading '*Saving your Private Key and Transferring to other Systems*'

Comment: Both those are options and we have gone with the later in the past but we would like to prevent our signing key from being given to lots of developers.

Comment: Then I suggest going with the former; if these 3rd party developers are reluctant to provide you with source code, you could always suggest they wrap it in a static library and re-factor their code appropriately. Both of which should be fairly trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Provisioning profile is only used along with certificate to sing the binary. Developer can create an unsigned binary and send it to you, so you can manually codesign it with your provisioning profile. I'm not sure if there is any difference between ad-hoc and appstore versions binary-wise, but I don't think so.

Comment: in the past there have been differences, e.g. entitlements for adHoc configuration, but with Build&Archive and later share/submit the codesigning is separated from the binary build. This is a great feature, as you can use the adhoc tested binary for the appstore now. Not sure though, if you can _load_ an archive from another machine into your xcode to sign and share/submit it.

Comment: You don't need to load it into organizer, you can use codesign from command line or with utility like this one: http://www.tuaw.com/2010/02/09/sdk-devsugar-re-signing-applications/ I'm not sure how to insert provisioning profile properly tho...

Comment: @ fichek - What I can't work out is where the provisioning profile is used / specified when I use the codesign utility

Comment: @marcus - The catch-22 we seem to be in is that in order to build & archive you need to sign the app with the a provisioning profile that matches the bundle id. It isn't possible for the developer to create this provisioning profile as it is our bundle id. Build & archive won't let you not sign the app. I can make xcode not care about provisioning profiles to get around this but then I am confused about what the app store provisioning profile actually does in the binary itself. I can't seem to specify a profile using codesign.

Comment: I would assume, only embedded.mobileprovision and _CodeSignature gets updated during signing. Could the developer use your bundle id (in plist) and for development just use a generic App Id (with wildcard) within his developer provisioning profile (######.*)?

Comment: so maybe I could copy over the correct provisioning file over embedded.mobileprovision and the use codesign to sign it